# data cell reflexion on javaFx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I try to populate my TableView with contacts . I checked for typos(get and set) as it is verified by the java machine for the columns implementation but nothing changes i still have the same error of data reflectivity

> Main Class

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = 
    FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("contactsScene.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Contact World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 500));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

> Contact Class

```
public class Contact {
    public SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    public SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    public SimpleStringProperty number;


    public Contact(String firstName, String lastName, String number) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.number = new SimpleStringProperty(number);


    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty firstNameProperty() {return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }
 }
```

> Controller Class

```
 import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
 import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
 import javafx.fxml.FXML;
 import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
 import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
 import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class Controller{
     @FXML
    private TableView<Contact> contactTableView;
    ObservableList<Contact>data=FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public void initialize(){
        data.addAll(new Contact("Joe","Factory","000000000"),
        new Contact("Mickael","Cell","000000000"),
        new Contact("Gerard","Data","00000000"),
        new Contact("john","Reflectivity","0000000000"));


        TableColumn firstNameCol=new TableColumn("First Name");
        firstnameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Contact, String>("firstName"));


        contactTableView.setItems(data);
        contactTableView.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol);

    }

}}
```

---

> FXML

```
     <?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
     <?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
     <?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
     <?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
     <?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
     <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

     <?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
     <BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
     xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" 
     fx:controller="contactManagement.Controller"><top><VBox>
     <MenuBar><Menu text="contacts" /> </MenuBar></VBox></top>
     <center>
     <TableView  fx:id="contactTableView">

     <columnResizePolicy>
     <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
     </columnResizePolicy>

     </TableView></center>
     </BorderPane>
```

---

> Stacktrace

févr. 06, 2019 3:47:23 PM javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory getCellDataReflectively
WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'firstName' in PropertyValueFactory: ***javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@69fe6c51 with provided class type: class contactManagement.ContactManager.Contact
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module javafx.base cannot access class contactManagement.ContactManager.Contact (in module Contact) because module Contact does not open contactManagement.ContactManager to javafx.base***
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.PropertyReference.getProperty(PropertyReference.java:199)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.getCellDataReflectively(PropertyValueFactory.java:182)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:154)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:133)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:593)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:646)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:469)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:120)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableSkinUtils.resizeColumnToFitContent(TableSkinUtils.java:119)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableSkinUtils.resizeColumnToFitContent(TableSkinUtils.java:86)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader.doColumnAutoSize(TableColumnHeader.java:573)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader.updateScene(TableColumnHeader.java:516)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader.lambda$new$0(TableColumnHeader.java:159)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.lambda$new$1(LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:181)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node$ReadOnlyObjectWrapperManualFire.fireSuperValueChangedEvent(Node.java:1054)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.invalidatedScenes(Node.java:1114)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.setScenes(Node.java:1152)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$2.onChanged(Parent.java:369)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.TrackableObservableList.lambda$new$0(TrackableObservableList.java:45)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.base/javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.setAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:90)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:116)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.updateContent(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:578)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.updateTableColumnHeaders(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:504)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.checkState(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:638)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.computePrefHeight(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:345)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:1031)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1559)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow.computePrefHeight(TableHeaderRow.java:376)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow.computeMinHeight(TableHeaderRow.java:369)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:1059)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1525)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.SkinBase.computeMinHeight(SkinBase.java:311)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.computeMinHeight(Control.java:512)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:1059)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1525)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildMinAreaHeight(Region.java:1915)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane.getAreaHeight(BorderPane.java:630)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane.computeMinHeight(BorderPane.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:1059)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1525)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane.layoutChildren(BorderPane.java:497)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1204)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:576)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1748)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$2.preferredSize(Scene.java:393)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.SceneHelper.preferredSize(SceneHelper.java:66)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window$12.invalidated(Window.java:1086)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:1174)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:1189)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:273)
    at Contact/contactManagement.Main.start(Main.java:16)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: module javafx.base cannot access class contactManagement.ContactManager.Contact (in module Contact) because module Contact does not open contactManagement.ContactManager to javafx.base
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:69)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.PropertyReference.getProperty(PropertyReference.java:197)
    ... 73 more

I just make a try for firstName at the moment .I think my imports are fine.

Comment: your Contact exposes a property for firstName, use that property (vs. the reflective access via PropertyValueFactory) in a cellValueFactory and you'll never again have issues with typos :) That said: your snippet looks okay, so the error is elsewhere - please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. If you use fxml, include the fxml file, if the app throws an exception, include the stacktrace

Comment: thanks @fabian for editing to make it readable :) Which exposes the evils of snippets that have never been run: there seem to be 2 TableColumns - one a global field named _firstName_ and another a local field named _firstNameCol_ - you configure the former with the valueFactory and add the latter to the table's columns ...

Comment: Sorry That's my first ever question , I rearranged it so you can read with the infos you asked

Comment: Found it was a package reference problem,i put my contact class in a package and javafx would not go in it , maybe you can tell how to assign it to javafx,because i just lamely repath my contact class in my main package